# Polo 9n SDI 2002

Tags: engine, diesel, power, polo

Help :-)

My son has bout a polo 9n sdi with 120000 miles on.  It was a bit smokey apperantly when he bought it.  I now have it here on my drive and it smokes on idle and has a neat smoke screen trick when you drive it.  I know they arnt the most powerful things but this struggles at the sight of a hill.  Mechanically its sound and body is spot on.
When you do drive it the diesel rattle increases to much louder levels along with the smoke screen.

I've changed oil air and fuel filters but it hasnt helped one jot.  \egr valve looks clean and its showing a few error codes.  Where do I start with this ? Cheers

VCDS-Lite Version: Release 1.2
Monday, 18 March 2019, 13:54:21.
Control Module Part Number: 038 906 012 AM
  Component and/or Version: 1,9l R4 EDC 0000SG 4203 
           Software Coding: 00002
            Work Shop Code: WSC 00788
                      VCID: 5BC9146FDA3D
           Additional Info: WVWZZZ9NZ2Y099582     VWZ7Z0B4833083
3 Faults Found:
17849 -  EGR Valve (N18): Open Circuit or Short to Ground
        P1441 - 35-10 -   - - Intermittent
19557 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
        P3101 - 35-10 - Please Register/Activate - Intermittent
17660 - Shareware Version. To Decode all DTCs
        P1252 - 35-10 - Please Register/Activate - Intermittent